# Как в Yii 2 указать выбранное значение в dropdown

Tags: yii2

не могу найти как указать значение выбранным в выпадающем списке

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'attr_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Attr::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    ['prompt'=>'Select...'] ) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Из _form не получается. можно указать в контролере

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Bonus();
    $model->attr_id = '2'; 

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
    {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```